# Selection Sort Java

Tags: java, arrays, selection-sort

I'm trying to sort an array of Coin objects in descending order based on their value. There is a getValue() method in my Coin class. My problem is that the end result is not sorted at all. This is what I end up getting. I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong any tips would be helpful

Before we sort:
[Coin[value=0.25,name=quarter], Coin[value=0.01,name=penny], Coin[value=0.1,name=dime], Coin[value=1.0,name=dollar], Coin[value=0.05,name=nickel]]

Expected: [Coin[value=0.25,name=quarter], Coin[value=0.01,name=penny], Coin[value=0.1,name=dime], Coin[value=1.0,name=dollar], Coin[value=0.05,name=nickel]]

After we sort:
[Coin[value=0.01,name=penny], Coin[value=0.1,name=dime], Coin[value=0.25,name=quarter], Coin[value=1.0,name=dollar], Coin[value=0.05,name=nickel]]

Expected: [Coin[value=1.0,name=dollar], Coin[value=0.25,name=quarter], Coin[value=0.1,name=dime], Coin[value=0.05,name=nickel], Coin[value=0.01,name=penny]]

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
   This class sorts an array of coins, using the selection sort
   algorithm.
*/
public class CoinSelectionSorter
{
   //
    private Coin[] list;

   /**
      Constructs a selection sorter.
      @param anArray the array to sort.
   */
   public CoinSelectionSorter(Coin[] anArray)
   {
      list = anArray;
   }

    public String toString()
   {
      return Arrays.toString(list);
   }
   /**
      Finds the largest coin in an array range.
      @param from the first position in a to compare
      @return the position of the largest coin in the
      range a[from] . . . a[a.length - 1]
   */
   public int maximumPosition(int from)
   {
      int max = from;
      for(int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++){
          if(list[i].getValue() > list[max].getValue()){
              max = i;
          }  
      }
      return max;
   }

   /**
      Sorts an array.
   */
   public void sort()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < list.length -1; i++){
          int max = maximumPosition(i);
          swap(i, max);
      }
   }

   /**
      Swaps two entries of the array.
      @param i the first position to swap
      @param j the second position to swap
   */
   public void swap(int i, int j)
   {
      Coin temp = list[i];
      list[i] = list[j];
      list[j] = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether this is your problem, but I think that everywhere that you've written `i < list.length-1`, it should have been `i < list.length`.

Comment: Also, on the same line, `int i = from + 1` rather than `int i = 0`.

Comment: Take a look at your maximumPosition() function. In your comments, you say the function should "return the position of the largest coin in the range a[from] . . . a[a.length - 1]". However, that's not what it's doing.

Comment: yeah the problem was using 0 instead of from and using i< list.length -1 instead of i<list.length. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

you can Introduce the array in a List, after sort your list and finally introduce this parameters into array again, it is easier than using these

in a class Coin, introduce **public class Coin implements Comparable**

and you should implement a method:**CompareTo(Coin p)**  // p is a example

within this method introduce : **return this.r-prueva.r;** // you use this for next steps Comparable.Sort in next steps

example:

```
public class Coin implements Comparable<Coin >{

    Integer r;
    String p;

    public Coin(Integer r,String p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.r = r;
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Coin test) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.r - test.r;
    }
}
```

thats okey... now in your class you can create a method or introduce this for sort the array:

```
List<Coin> fileList = Arrays.asList(list); // Introduce Array in List

Collections.sort(list); // sort List

list = filelist.toArray(list) // introduce the sorted list in array
```

is very easy... if you want, if not understand me for my language, i can show this code that does what you need:

Your coin class implementing with comparable might be so...

```
  public class Coin implements Comparable<Coin >{

        Integer r;
        String p;

        public Coin(Integer r,String p) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.r = r;
            this.p = p;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Coin test) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.r - test.r;
        }
    }
```

Your Class CoinSelectionSorted might be so...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CoinSelectionSorter{

....

    public void sort() {

       Coin[] list =  new Coin[] {new Coin(2, "Johan"),
                                    new Coin(5, "peter"),
                                    new Coin(1, "robin"),
                                    new Coin(15, "walker"),
                                    }; // example data;

       List <Coin> p = Arrays.asList(list);

       Collections.sort(p);
       System.out.println(p); // only good print if you have implement ToString in class coin

      list = p.toArray(list); your sorted array.


    }
}
 ....
```

I hope I've helped

Good Lucky